# MvvmCross: TwoWay bindings with MonoTouch.Dialog

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog, mvvmcross

Full source for this issue can be found here: https://github.com/Cheesebaron/MvvmCross.SettingsSample

My main concern lies in the SettingsView, where I try to bind some simple BooleanElements:

```
this.Root = new RootElement("Settings")
            {
                new Section("Test", string.Format("Choose to see your own location on the map.{0}Choose to allow shake gestures.{0}Choose whether you want to receive notifications.", Environment.NewLine))
                {
                    new BooleanElement("Show my location", ViewModel.ShowMyLocation).Bind(this, "{'Value':{'Path':'ShowMyLocation','Mode':'TwoWay'}}"),
                    new BooleanElement("Shake gestures", ViewModel.ShakeGestures).Bind(this, "{'Value':{'Path':'ShakeGestures','Mode':'TwoWay'}}"),
                    new BooleanElement("Notifications", ViewModel.Notifications).Bind(this, "{'Value':{'Path':'Notifications','Mode':'TwoWay'}}"),
                },
            };
```

My problem resides in that the bindings only seem to work one way, even though I explicitly specify that it is `TwoWay`. The two way bindings seem to work fine on WP7 and Android, so I know the view model is ok. But either I am missing some code for the two way bindings or something is wrong or missing in the framework.

This issue is also there if I try with other types of elements like `CheckboxElement` or `StyledStringElement`. Also my own made elements...

Comment: Thanks for the sample. For the Boolean sample, I'm guessing this must be a bug. Possibly that I included the wrong class in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/master/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Dialog/MvxTouchDialogBindingSetup.cs - maybe CheckboxElement needs to be BaseBooleanElement. For StyledStringElement, I'm not sure - I don't really understand how to make StyledStringElement editable? I'll try to take a look tonight when I'm back in front of the mac.

Comment: Ah, wait a sec. StyledStringElement works, but it is like the view does not update on its own. So if you tap the cell it updates. So for some reason the cell is not notified of the change. (Another issue?)

Comment: Still looking at this (updating XCode and Monotouch and ...) but with the StyledStringElement I'm wondering a redraw needs to be forced using cell.SetNeedsDisplay (and maybe cell.Backbground.SetNeedsDisplay too?). Will look at this when the updates are finished.

Comment: I am back at a Mac computer on Thursday if you need me to test stuff. But I think you are right about calling SetNeedsDisplay. MonoTouch.Dialog does not seem to be designed to alter values contained in the views from the code behind it and works a lot better when there are touches on the screen that force redraws that way.

Comment: Thanks again - I've pushed some code and tested this against your sample app. It seems the Booleans are 2-way updating now. There's still no progress on the StyledStringElement - will try to get a test project up and running to look at this tomorrow night!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the comments above, this feels like this is a few separate problems:

- the BooleanElement wasn't correctly linked into [MvxTouchDialogBindingSetup.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/master/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Dialog/MvxTouchDialogBindingSetup.cs) - I have hopefully now fixed this - see this commit - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/commit/38e5f08acaffa6ac76d060d104f841f2765d234c - tested with your test project
- the StyledStringElement may simply need a "kick" to force it to redraw - so we may need to call `cell.SetNeedsDisplay()` - and maybe also `cell.Backbground.SetNeedsDisplay()` - I don't have a test case for this at present.
- your new cells may need to be linked in using new binding entries in your Setup.cs

Thanks for reporting these issues - and for following up with a test case. I will see if I can work out how to include some more formal test cases within the mvx repository.

---

As a future work item, I'd also quite like to formalise the `Value` and `ValueChanged` relationship - I think a general rule can be provided so that all Elements with Value and ValueChanged will support databinding - added as issue https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/26.